# using static variable in a method vs static property

Tags: php

Two examples:

```php
class StaticProperty 
{
    private static $staticProperty;

    private function someFunction()
    {
        if (null === self::$staticProperty) {
            //...havy work.
            self::$staticProperty = $result;
        }
        return self::$staticProperty;

    }
}
```

vs

```php
class StaticVariable 
{
    private function someFunction()
    {
        static $staticVar;

        if (null === $staticVar) {
            //...havy work.
            $staticVar = $result;
        }
        return $staticVar;

    }
}
```

Is there a difference between these examples? The static property is used only in one method of the class.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this example, the main different is that you don't have access in other method to static value declared inside function

```
<?php

class StaticProperty 
{
    private static $staticProperty = 'init property';

    private function someFunction()
    {
        if ('init property' === self::$staticProperty) {
            //...havy work.
            self::$staticProperty = 'my result in property';
        }
        return self::$staticProperty;

    }

    public function getResult()
    {
        var_dump(self::$staticProperty);
        return $this->someFunction();
    }
}

class StaticVariable 
{
    private function someFunction()
    {
        static $staticVar = 'init variable';

        if ('init variable' === $staticVar) {
            //...havy work.
            $staticVar = 'my result in variable';
        }
        return $staticVar;

    }

    public function getResult()
    {
        //var_dump(self::$staticVar);// it will call "Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property:.."
        return $this->someFunction();
    }
}

$staticVariable = new StaticVariable();
var_dump($staticVariable->getResult());

$staticPropertyClass = new StaticProperty();
var_dump($staticPropertyClass->getResult());
```

Result:

```
string(21) "my result in variable"
string(13) "init property"
string(21) "my result in property"
```

Comment: I had wanted to know other reasons. It seems there are no other cases where a static property would be more preferable to a static variable, except the case that you pointed to. Thanks.